# Finding out address of SMBIOS Entry point from command line

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, x86, bios

From https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_BIOS

> The SMBIOS Entry Point Table is located somewhere between the addresses 0xF0000 and 0xFFFFF, and must be on a 16-byte boundary. To find the specific location of the start of the table it is necessary to search that region of memory for the string "*SM*", and then check the structure's checksum (add all bytes and see if the lowest 8 bits of the result are zero).

How do i find out the exact address from command line:

```
# cat /dev/mem | grep '_SM_'
Binary file (standard input) matches
cat: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Beware that there are MMIO registers in some parts of physical address space.  Reading them has side effects.  This is part of why even root can't read `/dev/mem` by default; it's restricted by a sysctl and/or some non-default Linux "capabilities". 
If you were going to do this, use `dd` with `bs=1k skip=...` to get it to seek in the input to the start of the `0xF0000` range that the documentation told you to grep in.

Comment: Anyway, I forget if grep has options to print the byte offset of a match.  If so use them, otherwise search with a hex editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dmidecode** utility (installed as part of the *dmidecode* package on Debian based systems such as Ubuntu) will show the SMBIOS entry point if run with the **--no-sysfs** option. The address is shown on the second line of output:

```
$ sudo dmidecode --no-sysfs
# dmidecode 3.2
# SMBIOS entry point at 0x000fxxxx
Found SMBIOS entry point in EFI, reading table from /dev/mem
...
```

The **biosdecode** and **dmidecode** utilities can be used to examine the tables.

**biosdecode** examines the memory directly (**/dev/mem** by default, but can be changed with the **-d** option) to find the SMBIOS table (and other tables). **dmidecode** will try to locate the DMI table in sysfs first (unless run with the **--no-sysfs** option) and will fall back to examining the memory.

Links:

- [dmidecode Home page](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/)
- [dmidecode Project page on Savannah](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dmidecode/)
- [dmidecode Git browser](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/dmidecode.git)